# redirecting my http://website to https://website doesn't work

Tags: docker, nginx, redirect, https

I would like to redirect all traffic to https for our web server. We're running a docker container with nginx.

When checking from within the server my redirection, it seems to be doing the redirection

```
$ curl -L -I  http://maxquant.org
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.19.10
Date: Tue, 21 Nov 2023 08:12:10 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 170
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://maxquant.org/

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
...
```

But when I'm typing http://maxquant.org (with or w.o. www) I get the standard nginx response (Welcome to Nginx ...), that all is well, but the redirection is not working.

I'm not sure, what else I need to change in the docker/nginx settings for the redirection to work.

the configurations of the docker are shown below. The parameter `${NGINX_DOMAIN}` is stated in a `.env` file.

nginx.conf.template

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name ${NGINX_DOMAIN};

  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl default_server;
  server_name ${NGINX_DOMAIN};

  gzip              on;
  ...

  location / {
     include uwsgi_params;
     uwsgi_pass maxquant_download_app:8001;
  }

  location /static {
      root /app/maxquant;
  }

  location /p/ {
      secure_link $arg_md5,$arg_expires;
      secure_link_md5 "$secure_link_expires$uri ${NGINX_SECRET}";

      if ($secure_link = "") {
          return 403;
      }

      if ($secure_link = "0") {
          return 410;
      }
      rewrite ^/p/(.*)$ /assets/$1;
   }

   location /assets/ {
       internal;
       root /app/maxquant;
   }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  maxquant_download_app:
    ...     
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build:
      context: ..
      network: host
      dockerfile: docker/nginx.dockerfile
      args:
      ...
  depends_on:
    - maxquant_download_app
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    restart: "always"
```

[EDIT:]
Using http gives me the standard Nginx welcome page, not the requested web site:

[image: using http]

Comment: Works for me. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

I am giving suggestion as an answer (not enough reputation to comment)

After making changes to the NGINX configuration file, remember to reload NGINX to apply the changes:

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

[image: UPDATE]

Comment: thanks, but that's not it. We have restarted the server as well as rebuilt the docker container multiple times since the first installation. But the redirection still doesn't work.

Comment: I ran `curl -I http://maxquant.org` and it is being redirected to https

Comment: maybe try to open it in the incognito

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned at the top of my question, it does the same for me. I see the redirection and it should work. But it's not.

Comment: I don't know if this has something to do with the problem or not, but we're using United-domain to host the web page. Can it be, that the problem is not on the server itself but somewhere in the settings on the united-domain host services?

Comment: may be idk but when I'm typing `http://maxquant.org` in the browser I'm being re-directed to https